# how to remove spaces between columns in bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm implementing a static website using Bootstrap, HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I created  a row that have 4 icons each in column, the problem is the row is not centered even when I use `justify-content-center` also the icons are far from each other so I want them to be too close.

Any help?

```html
  <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5 ">
        <div class="col">
                <h1 style=" text-transform: capitalize; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;text-align: center;">our services
                </h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row " style="  margin:auto;     font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;">
        <div class="col">
          
                <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/images/svg/005-coding.svg"
                    style="width: 120px; margin: auto;" alt="none">
             
            
        </div>

        <div class="col">
     
                <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/images/svg/002-joystick.svg"
                    style="width: 120px; margin: auto;" alt="icon">
              
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          
                <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/images/svg/007-iphone.svg"
                    style="width: 120px; margin: auto;" alt="">
               
        
        </div>

        <div class="col">
           
                <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/images/svg/006-monitor.svg"
                    style="width: 120px; margin: auto;" alt="">
              
           
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That is how columns work. If you use 4 columns, it divides all of the available space into 4. If you want the icons beside each other, then put them beside each other instead of in columns.

Answer (score 0):

try using align-item:center and plzz be more specific with your question ..